# how to pass universal reference as const pointer?

Tags: c++

hello thank you for looking at my question
I am Korean, so my English is not good, so the question may be awkward. I express my apologies in advance.

I want to implement the task of writing data to a stream using a template.

```
template <typename T>
bool Write(const T* source) { return Write(source, sizeof(T)); }
bool Write(const void* in_buffer, const unsigned int in_byte_count);

template <typename T>
StreamWriter& StreamWriter::operator<<(T&& source)
{
    Write<T>(&source);
    return *this;
}
```

What I want is to properly call Write from operator<< .
However, this code doesn't compile.

I realized that passing the reference by removing the reference using std::remove_reference_t works fine.

I used reference to reduce copying costs.
But I'm afraid that using std::remove_reference_t is obscuring its semantics.

Is there any other good way?

Comment: Why write `<T>` at all?  Deduction should work fine here.

Comment: Note that using `std::remove_reference_t` here, while unnecessary, is harmless: it's simply a transformation on the _type_ and doesn't change the fact that only an address is being passed to `Write`.

Comment: Why are you using a universal reference at all?  You throw away the information it carries about the lvalue or rvalue status of the argument.  Just accept a `const T&` in your `operator<<` overload and all of the complexity about `T` sometimes being a reference goes away.

Comment: [OT]: That way to write data to stream has flows (endianess, data with pointer/reference).

Answer (score 7):

You can simply let the template argument be deduced:

```
Write(&source);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need universal reference here `const T& source` is enough and simpler.

That would also solve the `<T>` issue BTW.

But you might just let regular deduction occur:

```
template <typename T>
StreamWriter& StreamWriter::operator<<(const T& source)
{
    Write(&source);
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Your code compiles fine.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

struct X {
    char str[6];
}; 

bool Write(const void* in_buffer, const unsigned int in_byte_count) {
    const char* p = (const char*)in_buffer;
    for ( unsigned int j=0; j<in_byte_count; ++j ) {
        printf( "%02x=%c ", p[j], p[j] );
    }
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
bool Write(const T* source) { 
    return Write(source, sizeof(T)); 
}

class StreamWriter {
public:
template <typename T>
StreamWriter& operator<<(T&& source)
{
    Write<T>(&source);
    return *this;
}

};

X getX() {
    X x;
    char hello[] = "Hello";
    memcpy(&x,hello,sizeof(x));
    return x;
}

int main() {

    StreamWriter sw;
    sw << getX();
}
```

Produces:

```
Program stdout
48=H 65=e 6c=l 6c=l 6f=o 00=
```

If you want to bind an lvalue then you'd better have another method to this purpose.

```
template <typename T>
StreamWriter& operator<<(const T& source)
{
    Write<T>(&source);
    return *this;
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/qc5GsoG1v

Comment: Now try with an lvalue: `auto x = getX(); sw << x;`

Comment: Well if you define a universal reference you would not be expecting an lvalue - you'd have to have another method for it.

Comment: Why not? It's kind of the point of forwarding references: to preserve the value category. They are meant to work with lvalues and rvalues alike. Otherwise you would just use an rvalue reference.

Comment: The use of `memcpy` is usually a indication that you could rewrite this in a better way in C++. (`X x { "Hello" };` would do the trick.) Furthermore you're not directly referring to the data you actually want to be copied. It should be `std::memcpy(&x.str,hello,sizeof(x.str));` and it would be preferrable to add `static_assert(sizeof(x.str) >= sizeof(hello));` just to be sure noone later modifies the value of `hello` possibly resulting in UB, if the string is expected to be 0-terminated somewhere in the program.

Comment: @fabian No not really. The standard C++ library is notoriously lacking of features.